# how can i open a smaller box in the same browser window

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to open a small dialog/window just like an android alert dialog when i click on a link on my website

I read about bootstrap modal,it looks like what i need, but i am not able to display a website inside a modal

This is an example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Large Modal</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" href="http://patecgroup.com" data-target="#myModal">Open Large Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" >
          <p> Where the website should be</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please how can i get a website inside the modal, or be able to create a window that can do that for me

**EDIT**
I have also tried the iframe tag inside the modal, and it doesnt work for all websites

Comment: If you need to display a whole website and not just some html, you may create a modal containing an iframe pointing to that website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Trigger Modal in iFrame</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <iframe src="http://heera.it" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>  
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: i just tried it, google doesnt show in the iframe it is just blank white

Comment: still not working with other links, just a white background

Comment: google not allows to run iframe in https websites.because of security issue.

Comment: Please check the google policy => https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/3gciBCSunnk/VRh2X56T8UQJ

Comment: oh okay, thanks, is there a way to make the frame take up the whole screen of the modal